# values set for updatepanel control are lost when returned to client - ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I am working on a legacy app, and am experiencing a bizarre problem. I am working on code that works in production but, on my local machine, and when I publish from my machine, the code no longer works. It is an ASP.NET web app targeting .NET v3.5. I have a hidden field within an update panel, and it has an AsyncPostBackTrigger that points to the click event of a button on the page. When the button is clicked, it sets the value of the hidden field. Then, when control returns to the client side, there is a Javascript function that needs to access the value within the hidden field. Everything works without any error but, within the Javascript, the hidden field value is empty. Here is some example code to demonstrate what I am talking about:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMyForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="myScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updControlDisplay" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnControl" runat="server"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>  
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSetVal" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSetVal" runat="server" Text="Set Value" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);

        function endRequest(sender, e) {
            alert('endRequest fired!');
            if ($("hdnControl").val() == "") {
                alert("Value is blank");
            }
        }
    </script>       
</body>
```

and in the code behind file:

```
Protected Sub btnSet_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSet.Click
    'This code runs without any problem when the btnSetVal button is clicked
    hdnControl.Value = "Y"
End Sub
```

as I said, the code is working on a production server right now but, if I run it in Visual Studio on my machine, it doesn't work. If I publish it to our development server, it doesn't work either. I would really appreciate any/all suggestions about how to debug this.

My development machine is Windows 7 and I am using IIS 7. The production machine (where the app works) uses IIS 6 as does the development machine I am publishing to.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you're setting `.Value` property of the button control `btnSetVal`, you never touch the hidden field. Technically this shouldn't even compile, because ASP.NET button doesn't have such property.

Change it to `hdnControl.Value = "Y"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it in my example. That was just an error I made in creating a simplified version of my code. The actual code is correct in that respect. Thanks again.

Comment: Understood. Ok, what about if instead of using `$("hdnControl").val()` to get the value you try `$get("hdnControl").value`?

Comment: Thanks for following up...the control is found but, there is no value in it...it is blank. So, the $get("") function gets the same results as the $("#") function does. It finds the control, but there is no value in the control. Thanks again (I am calling it a night. I will be back on this in the morning).

Comment: Page lifecycle can also be tricky. Try placing check for hidden field instead of `function endRequest` to `function pageLoad` (no need to explicitly add it as a handler - it's already added for you)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this:

```
if ($("hdnControl").val() == "")
```

with this:

```
if ($("#<%= hdnControl.ClientID %>").val() == "")
```

since `hdnControl` is an ASP.NET HiddenField.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was one of my first thoughts. But the controls are rendered with IDs as they are defined in the source code. If I put             var elmnt = $("#hdnMarginChanged");
            if (elmnt) {
                alert("The value in element = " + elmnt.val());
            } in the endRequest function, it prints out "The value in element = ". So the element is found but, there is no value in it.